# How to connect to multiple endpoints in the robot framework using restinstance library

Tags: robotframework

How to define multiple endpoints in the settings of robot

My expectation will be like this. Defining two urls in the settings

```
***Settings***
Library         REST                  ${API_URL_1}               URL_1
Library         REST                  ${API_URL_2}               URL_2
```

and it will called in the testcases as

```
*** Test Cases ***
Scenario-1
GET          ${URL_1}/getsomething
get the response to a variable (say: data)
POST        ${URL_2}/dosomething       ${data}
```

will that possible using restinstace library?

Answer (score 2):

According with the Library documentation:

> Sends a GET request to the endpoint.
>
> The endpoint is joined with the URL given on library init (if any). If
> endpoint starts with http:// or https://, it is assumed an URL outside
> the tested API

That means, if you build your test like:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Scenario 1
   GET   http://URL_1/getsomething
   GET   http://URL_2/getsomething
```

Will connect you to different endpoints.
Or you can store your URLs in variables and call the ones you want:

```
*** Variables ***
${URL_1}   http://myfirsturl
${URL_2}   http://myotherturl

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario 1
   GET   ${URL_1}/getsomething
   GET   ${URL_2}/getsomething
```